# Error con la librería Calligraphy

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Tengo un error en el Gradle con la dependencia de esta librería:

```
compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
```

Surgen los siguientes errores:

```
    /Users/myUser/AndroidStudioProjects/myProject/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v23/values-v23.xml

Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.

Error:(24) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/myUser/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/21.1.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Debes Poner el jar de calligraphy en el lib de tu proyecto de android y luego sincronizarlo, también  depende de la versión del jar para que se ejecute correctamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]